# structure models for performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC is there a performance gain/loss in how you place your model definitions?

Say for an employee model, you have a name space of AppName.Employee and three classes, NewEmployee, ViewEmployee & EditEmployee each linking to a different view in a T-Sql database.

Is there any difference in performance in having them all in one name space or separating them out into their own name space and class file?

I know this is an example with just three classes but on a larger scale would it matter? or would the only implication be when you compile it as apposed to run time?

Comment: Welll, model/view/controller is a theoretical concept, and the answer would likely depend on what language you're using a MVC pattern in. But even then, bear in mind that brain time is more expensive than computation time, so even if there were a tiny performance difference, you have a loss in readability, manageability, reusability of your code that you need to take into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any change in the performance if you put all of your classes in one namespace. Actually even it would be better to put all your classes that represent actions of the same "real" object in one namespace to be more readable and managable in the future. You would slow your performance if you put all the logic in one class and then call everything from it, which would be dumb and would make your code spaghetti.